# printing multiple lines with two for loop

Tags: java, arrays

I have to write program to check if all the elements of the given 2nd array are positive
if all the elements positive it print
"All the elements of your array are positive"

here is my code:
the problem with the code that it print this line multiple times! And I need it to print only one time.

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        int [][] multi = {{2,5,7,-2,-8},{3,7,4,4,5},{2,1,3,8,9},{5,4,8,2,1},{7,8,9,6,-2}};
        multiArr(multi);

        }


public static void multiArr(int [] [] arr){

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<arr[0].length; j++)

            if(arr[i][j]>0)
                System.out.println("All the elements of your array are positive");


            }

}
```

here is the result in the Console :

```
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
All the elements of your array are positive
:
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? It looks like one. In either case, please take a look at http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have your print statement inside the loop, so if the element you are viewing is positive, it is going to display "positive" on the screen. My suggestion, add a boolean variable already set to true, then if the element is negative, change it to false inside your loop, then return that variable. Use that to display your positive string outside of the loop. Hope this helps!

Comment: yes it work with the boo-lean variable, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop should be like:

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
for(int j=0; j<arr[0].length; j++)
    if(arr[i][j]<0) {
        System.out.println("Some element in array are negative");
        return;//return from method
    }
 System.out.println("All elements in array are positive");
```